# Assigning pointer to different pointer (counting sort)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some issues with my implementation of counting sort. I am trying to reassign some pointers, however this does not work. I know I could use a loop to copy the sorted values from "sorted_arr" into my "values" array but I would like to understand why my version does not work. Thanks in advance!

```
void countingsort(unsigned int *values, unsigned long nofelements) {
    unsigned int *aux_arr;
    unsigned int *sorted_arr;
    unsigned int *temp_arr;
    long i;

    aux_arr = calloc((MAXSORTVALUE + 1), sizeof(*aux_arr));
    assert(aux_arr != NULL);
    sorted_arr = malloc(nofelements * sizeof(*sorted_arr));
    assert(sorted_arr != NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < nofelements; i++) { 
        aux_arr[values[i]]++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= MAXSORTVALUE; i++) {
        aux_arr[i] = aux_arr[i] + aux_arr[i - 1];
    }

    for (i = nofelements - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sorted_arr[aux_arr[values[i]] - 1] = values[i];
        aux_arr[values[i]]--;
    }

    temp_arr = values; // here is the reassignment

    values = sorted_arr; // and here

    free(temp_arr);
    free(aux_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` is a pointer that points to a array sent by the calling function. So changing the value of `values` will not change the actual array in the calling function. this is causing problem that the actual array in calling function will not change.
To have the change applied to original array either take pointer to pointer as parameter `int **` and change the value of pointer in calling function or modify the `values` array itself.